# Is it possible to Map Function keys to something else on macOS?

Tags: macos, keybindings, touch-bar

I'm on Apple Silicon MacBook Pro.

The Touch Bar is broken.

I'm in a program where I need to use some of the F keys, and I'm not able to create shortcuts within the program.

Are there anyways I can map the F keys to something else?

Comment: F key == Function key? Which application are you referring to, and which commands? Can these commands also be triggered via the menu bar?

Comment: @nohillside I needed the F1, F2, F3 ... keys. And no, in that application there was no way to trigger the functionality without using the F keys

Comment: How is the Touchbar 'broken'? If it's a hardware failure, then you should take it back for a replacement/repair. (Unless you dropped a brick onto it, or something.)

Comment: @MartinCarlsson does this [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/423528/151404) describe the issue you're having?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with this program: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/

And imported this: https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#fn_plus_numbers_to_function_keys