# How to immediately show the function keys on the 2020 MBP M1 Touch Bar?

Tags: keyboard, big-sur, settings, keybindings, touch-bar

I am switching from a 2018 MBP i7 with a touch bar to a 2020 MBP M1. The older machine is still running macOS Catalina (v10.15.7) whereas the newer one came with macOS Big Sur preinstalled (v11.4). One thing I cannot figure out is how to force the M1 to show the function keys *immediately* upon pressing the  <kbd>fn</kbd> key. Check out the different **Keyboard** system preferences:

##### 2018

[image: 2018 MBP on macOS v10.15.7]

##### 2020

[image: 2020 MBP on macOS v11.4]

##### Video

[Click here to see the difference in a video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/quKMbozDFwvZFgfF6).

This delay is big enough for me to miss the  <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> or  <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> shortcuts that focus on the Menu Bar and Dock, respectively. While I realize that I have the option to show nothing but the function keys on the touch bar, I still find the touch bar useful enough to leave it as is. (I've set it up to change to function keys in certain apps like iTerm.)

Does anybody know of a script or a workaround how to bring back the macOS Catalina behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the immediate issue at hand, set the "Press …" to "Do Nothing:"
[image: Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard]

---

However, I still wanted to be able to tap  <kbd>fn</kbd> twice to start dictation. I was able to re-enable that functionality with the help of a third-party app called [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/). Here's how:

1. In Preferences » Keyboard » Dictation, create a custom shortcut:
   [image: Preferences » Keyboard » Dictation]
   (I used <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>clear</kbd>, but it doesn't really matter)
2. In BetterTouchTool, record a new Key Sequence for  <kbd>fn</kbd> <kbd>fn</kbd> and assign the Action to " Send Keyboard Shortcut" to match the shortcut from the previous step:
   [image: BetterTouchTool Key Sequence]

Comment: It still works on macOS Ventura 13.1 and BetterTouchTool v3.952.

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround that I know of is to choose `Do Nothing` under `Press` .

This would disable the short-press functionality and it will skip straight to the Press and Hold functionality.

Answer (score 0):

## This is unique to new Mac models

This difference is due to your [hardware having the globe key](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/touch-bar-mchlbfd5b039/mac) (see bold):

> To show the function keys in the Touch Bar, press and hold the Fn key or the Globe key  (**depending on your Mac model**) on the keyboard.

Older Macs still display the same options on Big Sur.

## Why there’s a delay

The delay is necessary given that this key also functions as a way to switch keyboards (holding vs. pressing).

## Potential workarounds

1. Try to only have 1 keyboard available (hopefully it skips the delay in this case)?
2. Try something like what was suggested [on a related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/423460/151404):

> I solved the issue with this program:
> https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/
>
> And imported this:
> https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#fn_plus_numbers_to_function_keys

Comment: Hi @JBallin and thanks for the suggestion. I looked into Karabiner and it seems like they have to the same issue:  
"It’s an issue of macOS, and unfortunately, Karabiner-Elements cannot avoid this issue. ([Source](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/help/troubleshooting/touch-bar-function-keys/).)"  

Besides, Karabiner would essentially change the shortcut to [ fn][control][2] and if I wanted that, I could have done so myself in Preferences » Keyboard » Shortcuts » Keyboard » ✅ Move focus to the menu bar ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/VdEyBUp.png)).

Comment:  - what about the first suggestion? I don’t have a model I can tinker with.

Comment: I only have one input source -- U.S. English ([proof](https://imgur.com/RfB0gGE)). Sorry for not addressing that suggestion sooner.